# jQuery Library that can a resizeable, rotatable and draggable line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, mouseevent

I want to know if there is an existing jQUery Library that can help me draw a line on screen. The line should be re-size, rotated and dragged using the mouse. See images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If there is none, what is my 'must to know' javascript thing to start building this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `jquery-ui` [resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/) and [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) with this jquery-ui [rotatable](https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable) plugin, You can take a look at this [demo](http://godswearhats.com/jquery-ui-rotatable/demo.html).

Comment: please include relevant code in your answer rather than link-only answers. I visited the jqueryui site just now and got 'website offline' - not v helpful, and is a prime example of the fact that LINKS BREAK